# 4WD Rear differential removed totally and have it a 2WD?

Tags: kia, 4wd, rear-differential, modification, rear-end

I have a 1997 Kia Sportage 4wd and it is having EXACTLY the problem that this pickup truck is having: (The sound the truck makes)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJUSEH0opi8&index=3&list=PLrsRTzxpFRawamXQq00GViR8v8TUnUKYk&t=0s

I have never used 4WD mode of my car.

Can I have the rear differential removed totally and have it a 2WD?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This will depend on the transfer box / centre diff - it may be possible or not...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i remove the rear diff in my land rover freelander?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/can-i-remove-the-rear-diff-in-my-land-rover-freelander)